# mySQL query to not skip "empty" results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT count(Distinct name) as total, DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%M %d, %Y') AS date_added 
FROM `submitted_changes` 
WHERE date_added >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK 
GROUP BY DATE(date_added)
```

It works great and returns rows that have a nicely formatted date and a total. Basically, this represents the number of submissions per day.

The problem I have is dealing with days with 0 submissions. I don't want to skip these days, but rather have the date shown and 0 for the `total`. Is there a way to ensure that when I do the query above (which only includes dates from the past week [7 days]) that I always get 7 rows back?

Comment: *"The problem I have is dealing with days with 0 submissions."* - If by that you mean "if the row is empty", then you could add an additional clause checking if it is empty with `AND|OR` (subquery), if that's what the question is about. You can also use a `CASE`.

Comment: Yes @Fred-ii- I suppose that's what I mean (I think) can you point me in the right direction for this subquery?

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/q/17832906/1415724 there could be something in there you can base yourself on. Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5520500/1415724

Comment: Actually @Fred-ii- I don't think that's the same. Each row has a single submission with a date. In my query, I'm counting the rows and grouping by date. The problem is that it skips the dates in my results when there are no submission (no rows). Is that the same issue?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402030/mysql-fill-missing-dates. I suggest using PHP to solve this issue because it will be an easier to read solution than solving this from MySQL itself.

Comment: @jorgonor Good grief...the mySQL looks like a disaster. How would you handle with PHP?

Comment: @jonmrich, in the question I quoted there is a simple solution in PHP, I would do it like that. You can even encapsulate it in a helper method if you have to reuse it through your application.

Comment: You want the system to return to you dates that are not in the table?  That's not how SQL works.  It retrieves data from the database;   databases don't make up data.  You can accomplish your goal by using a numbers/calendar table or use user variables and generate the dates between dates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402030/mysql-fill-missing-dates  another way would be to create an inline view that does 6 unions and 7 selects one for today, today-1 today-2 ... and use that as the main table and you left join your table guaranteeing all 7 days.

Comment: `OR date_added =''` if empty I guess. Hard to say. Can you edit your post to include the schema/values? I may not be able to solve it, but others may be able to  @jonmrich if default values are `NULL` then you may have to use `OR date_added =NULL`. Again, hard to say; am kind of guessing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most straightforward way to pad empty dates in sql results (on either mysql or perl end)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752/what-is-the-most-straightforward-way-to-pad-empty-dates-in-sql-results-on-eithe)

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need an existence of a record per each date. Since this is not the case in your `submitted_changes` table - I'll suggest to create a date table (if you don't have it already).

*Note* - for the shortest version, check the last edit at the bottom:

Here is an example with a **temporary table**. First run:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dates AS 
SELECT DATE(curdate()-num) as date_col
FROM
(
SELECT 0 as num
UNION
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 4
UNION
SELECT 5
UNION
SELECT 6) sub
```

This will create a table with 7 relevant dates.
Now `left join` it with your data:

```
SELECT 
      count(Distinct name) as total,
      DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%M %d, %Y') AS date_added 
FROM dates LEFT JOIN submitted_changes 
               on (dates.date_col = DATE(submitted_changes.date_added))
GROUP BY date_col
```

---

You can also run it as a **one-shot query** (with no `create` statement):

```
SELECT 
      count(Distinct name) as total,
      DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%M %d, %Y') AS date_added 
FROM 
(SELECT DATE(curdate()-num) as date_col
FROM
(
SELECT 0 as num
UNION
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 4
UNION
SELECT 5
UNION
SELECT 6) sub) dates
LEFT JOIN submitted_changes 
               on (dates.date_col = DATE(submitted_changes.date_added))
GROUP BY date_col
```

---

Another approach is a **permanent `dim_date`**. Here is a sample code for static table (with more extra fields):

```
CREATE TABLE dim_date (
  id            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  date      date, 
  day       int(11), 
  month         int(11), 
  year      int(11),
  day_name  varchar(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX date_index (date)
)
```

and then populate it:

```
SET @currdate := "2015-01-01";
SET @enddate := "2025-01-01";

delimiter $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS BuildDate$$
CREATE PROCEDURE BuildDate()
    BEGIN
            WHILE @currdate < @enddate DO
            INSERT INTO dim_date  (date, day, month, year, day_name)
            VALUES (
                    @currdate,  DAY(@currdate),  MONTH(@currdate), 
              YEAR(@currdate), DAYNAME(@currdate)
);
            SET @currdate := DATE_ADD(@currdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END WHILE;
    END$$
CALL BuildDate();
```

Then you can finally run your query with a `left join`:

```
SELECT 
      count(Distinct name) as total,
      DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %d, %Y') AS date_added 
FROM dim_date LEFT JOIN submitted_changes 
               on (dim_date.date = DATE(submitted_changes.date_added))
WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK 
GROUP BY date
```

This would return a line per each date, even if there are no records in `submitted_changes` for them.

---

**Edit:** another *one-shot* super short version inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql/21286493#21286493):

```
SELECT 
      count(Distinct name) as total,
      DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %d, %Y') AS date_added 
(SELECT date(curdate()-id%7) as date
FROM submitted_changes
GROUP BY num) dates LEFT JOIN submitted_changes 
              on (date.dates = DATE(submitted_changes.date_added))
GROUP BY date
```